# mapObject.updateSize() is not working in tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive

Tags: dictionary, angularjs-directive, resize, openlayers-3

I am trying to resize the map which is similar to the issue raised here

https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/issues/125

but doing the way specified in query i am able to get the map object but when i do update size on it

I am getting the error has laneMap.updateSize is not a function

my funtion is :

```
 $scope.mapResize= function () {
    var laneMap=mapService.getMapObject();
    console.log(laneMap)
   laneMap.updateSize();
  }
```

i am getting the map object from my service

Please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my map disappearing when I navigated to a new tab and then back so wanted to redraw the map when the view was activated ( $ionicView.enter ).

A couple of tips:
ensure that 'olData' is injected into your controller which provides you with access to the olData variable in your controller. Then to perform a size update do something like:

```
olData.getMap().then(function (map) { map.updateSize();  });
```